# how to fix "could not be scrolled into view" error in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am scrolling an element into view via JavaScript, but when trying to click on that element an exception is being raised which says the element cannot be scrolled into view, but when I look at the browser, it has been scrolled into view. I've even tried waiting for the item to be clickable but the same error is still thrown.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could provide any solutions in python, but java is okay. Thanks you. :)

Here is my code:

```py
for i in range(len(units)):
    matchCnt += '0'
    for name in className:
        if name.lower() in str(units[i].text).lower():
            matchCnt[i] = str(int(matchCnt[i]) + 1)
            if int(matchCnt[i]) == len(className):
                browser.execute_script('return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', units[i])
                WebDriverWait(browser, 200).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, classId)))
                #element[i].click()
                #WebDriverWait(browser, 200).until(webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(units[i]))
                #time.sleep(5)
                units[i].click()
                doesMatch = True
    if doesMatch:
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Javascript to click on the unit, by this way the element will be clicked though not scrolled element into view.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",unit[i])
```

Comment: Yes! The problem's all fixed now. I've been stuffing around with this for like 2 weeks now. Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help. :)